# Put all commits from feature branch on top of master branch

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have a feature branch which was created from master branch with commit-1. After some time status is as:

Feature branch :

Commit-1, commit - A, Commit - B

Master branch :

Commit - 1, Commit - 2, Commit - 3

**What is needed**

Want to rebase all the changes from feature branch to master branch.

**Expected new history :**

Commit - 1, Commit - 2, Commit - 3, commit - A, Commit - B

**Issue facing**

Performed below commands

```
git checkout feature

git rebase master
```

There were some conflicts in say file-1, file-2 and auto merging failed. Resolved those conflicts manually and did

```
git rebase --continue
```

But it has created a single git commit instead of getting all the history of commits for me.

Can anyone suggest, how to retain the history of commits here?

Comment: What you are doing is what should be done. I tihink it is better if you provide us with cli commands and their outputs while you were doing the rebase. And a good command to show before starting the rebase would be: `git log --oneline --graph feature master` so that we get a clear idea of the layout of the branches.

Comment: For @eftshift0's comment- show that log graph before and after the rebase to highlight the issue you are facing.

Comment: If commit A or commit B on the feature branch was redundant with commit 2 or commit 3 on master it will be empty. Git will throw out empty commits. Possibly after resolving the conflicts a commit wound up making no change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the issue

I was not doing the git rebase --continue at the right time, order should be

```
git checkout feature
```

```
git rebase master
```

If there are conflicts, files are shown as both modified

```
git status
```

Find the files which are modified by both, resolve the merge conflict and then do

```
git rebase --continue
```

Continue doing the same for all the commits in the feature branch and when all commits are done, it will finish rebasing.